# Doing send operations atomically

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, contract-design, out-of-gas

I have three addresses `a1`, `a2`, `a3` to which I want to send one third of a contract's balance in the minimal number of transactions (ideally, just one) and without storage. I could have a function as follows:

```
function withdraw() {
    uint split = this.balance/3;

    a1.send(split);
    a2.send(split);
    a3.send(split);
}
```

The problem is in regards to atomicity and out-of-gas. [As I understand](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19143/out-of-gas-and-atomicity), an out-of-gas exception will revert operations, but `send` operations are an exception:

> When exceptions happen in a sub-call, they “bubble up” (i.e.
>   exceptions are rethrown) automatically. Exceptions to this rule are
>   `send` and the low-level functions `call`, `delegatecall` and `callcode` –
>   those return `false` in case of an exception instead of “bubbling up”.

So it is possible for `a1` to repeatedly call `withdraw()` with just enough gas for the first `send`, thereby draining the contract for itself.

One could try do some mechanism design so that the caller withdraws last. For example:

```
function withdraw() {
    if(msg.sender != a1 && msg.sender != a2 && msg.sender != a3) return;
    uint split = this.balance/3;

    if(msg.sender != a1) a1.send(split);
    if(msg.sender != a2) a2.send(split);
    if(msg.sender != a3) a3.send(split);

    // msg.sender goes last
    msg.sender.send(split);
}
```

The problem here is that `a1` and `a3` can collude to cheat on `a2`. Indeed, `a3` can repeated call `withdraw` with just enough gas to drain the contract to `a1`.

I guess it is possible to keep track of withdrawals that have occurred with storage, but that seems like overkill.

Is there a way to make several `send` operations atomically, similar to how Bitcoin can have multiple UTXOs in a single transaction?

Answer (score 2):

You're right about the risk of DoS from one of the recipients.

As a general rule, limit function interactions to one untrusted contract at time.

Think about your `withdraw()` function as dealing with only one of them at a time. They will individually claim their due.

Something like:

```
function withdraw(uint amount) returns(bool success) {
  amount = balance[msg.sender]
  balance[msg.sender] = 0;
  if(amount==0) throw;
  LogWithdrawal(msg.sender, amount);
  msg.sender.transfer(amount);
  return true;
}
```

Hope it helps.